# Lindeberg-Feller CLT example

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to understand probability and measure theory. I found some difficulties to understand this example, 7.9, application to (Lindeberg-Feller CLT). I have no idea how by (DOM) , Dominance, and the finite variance they reach they conclude the proof. Please refer to the link provided titled, the example,  to look to my question.

[Book] Rick Durrett. Probability: theory and examples. Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2010. References: [Section 3.4, 3.6].

I appreciate any help in understanding this material. 
  [The Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CWcd.png)

Comment: Which book are you using? Or simply add some necessary information so others can help.

Comment: edited the question @novavita

Comment: What is it you are struggling to understand? The example is simply verifying that the regular CLT holds, assuming that the Lindeberg-Feller CLT holds. To do this, they simply need to check conditions $1$ and $2$ are both satisfied, which in both cases are fairly trivial.

Comment: @Jason thank you for your reply. I don't see how and why  they applied the DOM, and why it mentioned  E[x^2]< infinity at the end of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this example is to show that the Lindeberg-Feller theorem conditions are satisfied by the standard sum of iid random variables case with finite variance.

In particular, the example verifies that condition (ii) of the Lindeberg-Feller theorem is satisfied:
\begin{align}
 \text{(ii) For all } \epsilon > 0, \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^n E(|X_{n,m}|^2; |X_{n, m}| > \epsilon) = 0
\end{align}
Since $|X_1|^2 \mathbb{1}_{|X_1| > \epsilon\sqrt{n}} \leq |X_1|^2$ and $E[|X_1|^2] < \infty$, dominated convergence implies
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} E[|X_1|^2;|X_1| > \epsilon\sqrt{n}] = 
E[|X_1|^2; |X_1| \geq \infty] = 0
\end{align}
and condition (ii) holds.

Comment: thank you greately. It might be a stupid question but why =0 at the end?

Comment: because the set for which $|X_1| \geq \infty$ has measure 0 since $X_1$ has finite expectation.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful

Comment: I am trying to check condition one. I do not know where to go from here. could you see what am I missing here please?  \begin{align}
 \text{(i) For all } \epsilon > 0,  \sum_{m=1}^n E(|X_{n,m}|^2) ---- (1)

 

\sum _{m=1}^n E[((X_m)^2)/2]
\end{align} how the sum of the variances  converge to one?